# NetSuite And/Or Filter

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a report in NetSuite. I want to filter out certain data in regards to one parameter, then I want to filter in data by using another parameter. Is there an AND/OR filter in NetSuite?

Answer (score 7):

If you are doing it using Netsuite Report/search interface, click on **Use Advanced Search** and then check **Use Expressions**. You would see the And/Or column in the Criteria Tab.

If you are doing it using Suit Script use Search Filter Expressions

```
//Define search filter expression
var filterExpression = [ 
   [ 'trandate', 'onOrAfter', 'daysAgo90' ],
   'or',
   [ 'projectedamount', 'between', 1000, 100000 ],
   'or',
   'not', [ 'customer.salesrep', 'anyOf ', -5] 
];
```

Comment: This works. Quote from the API: Note that the filters argument in nlapiSearchRecord(type, id, filters, columns) refers to either a search filter list (nlobjSearchFilter[]) or to a search filter expression (Object[]). With the object reference returned, you can then use any of the following nlobjSearchFilter methods to filter your results.

Comment: Is there a way to use FilterExpressions using SuiteTalk .NET client? @Phil_1984_

Comment: Please could you look at my question, which is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494717/sss-invalid-srch-filter-join-when-using-filter-expression-on-joined-custom-field

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve the same with the saved search option also.
Go to : Lists --> Search --> saved search --> new
create a new saved search and on the criteria sub-tab 
mark on Use Expressions box. Place your filter conditions with 'And/Or' conjunction.

Otherwise use the followings:
var filters = new Array(); 
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord01',null,'contains','alpha').setOr(true); 
filters[1]= new nlobjSearchFilter( 'custrecord02', null, 'contains', 'x').setOr(true);

Comment: Just tried this and it works.  You would have thought that you could just use a string array in the 4th argument, but you cant.

Answer (score 2):

We also can use sql OR in formula search like shown below

```
var flt = new Array();
var strFormula = "case when {internalid}=123 OR {internalid}=456 then 'yes' else 'no' end";
flt.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('formulatext',null,'is','yes').setFormula(strFormula));

var col = new Array();
col.push(new nlobjSearchColumn("entityid"));

var rslt = nlapiSearchRecord('customer',null,flt,col);
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the situation in which i need to use AND/OR filter in Netsuite.
I achieved this by :

**You can directly give static filter value by**

```
filters: [
    ['internalid', 'anyof', parseInt(customer_internal_id)],
    'and',
    ['transaction.internalidnumber', 'equalto', parseInt(salesorder_internal_id)],
    'and',
    ['transaction.mainline', 'is', 'true']
]
```

**If you want to dynamically add filter** ,
you store/push your filter to a array and set this array as filter.
You can achieve this by

```
var individualFilter = [], combineIndividualFilter = [], defaultFilters = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
    individualFilter[0] = ['formulatext: {category}','startswith',"Related Items for "+ itemName[i].split(" :")[0]];
    combineIndividualFilter.push(individualFilter[0]);
    if ((i + 1) != numLines) {
        combineIndividualFilter.push('OR');
    }
}
defaultFilters.push(combineIndividualFilter);
defaultFilters.push('AND');
defaultFilters.push(['website', 'anyof', 3 ]);
defaultFilters.push('AND');
defaultFilters.push(['formulatext: {storedisplayimage}','isnotempty', null ]);
```

and finally by setting

```
filters : defaultFilters
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, NetSuite's Saved Search functionality allows you to use both AND & OR criteria when defining your search filters. This feature provides a powerful way to narrow down the data in your report based on multiple conditions.

#### Steps to set up AND/OR criteria in a Saved Search:

1. **Navigate to Create or Edit a Saved Search**: Go to the respective module (like Transactions, Customers, Items, etc.) and select `New Search` or edit an existing one.
2. **Go to Criteria Tab**: This is where you'll define your filters.
3. **Set Up AND Criteria**: By default, each criterion you add is an AND condition. This means if you set up multiple criteria rows, a record needs to satisfy all those conditions to appear in your results. For example, if you set:

   - `Status` is `Pending Approval`
   - `Amount` is greater than `1000`

   This would translate to: `Status` is `Pending Approval` **AND** `Amount` is greater than `1000`.
4. **Set Up OR Criteria**: To use OR:

   - Click on the first criterion you want as part of the OR group.
   - Choose the `...` (or sometimes labeled `More`) option on the left of the criterion row.
   - Select `New OR Group`. This will group the selected criterion into an OR group.
   - Add more criteria to this OR group by selecting the `+` on the right side of the OR group box. Any criteria added within this box will be treated as OR conditions.

   For example, if you set within an OR group:

   - `Department` is `Sales`
   - `Department` is `Marketing`

   This would translate to: `Department` is `Sales` **OR** `Department` is `Marketing`.
5. **Mixing AND and OR**: You can have multiple criteria outside the OR group (which are AND conditions by default) and still have one or more OR groups. This allows you to combine AND & OR logic. For instance:

   - `Status` is `Pending Approval` (AND condition)
   - OR Group:

     - `Department` is `Sales`
     - `Department` is `Marketing`

   Translation: `Status` is `Pending Approval` **AND** (`Department` is `Sales` **OR** `Department` is `Marketing`).
6. **Continue with your Saved Search setup**, adding results columns, sorting, etc., and then save your search.

The above steps allow you to create robust searches with complex conditions