# Netsuite nlapiSearchRecord Expression filters not working

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Running into an issue with the nlapiSearchRecord() I can apply the nlobjSearchFilter() object to the searchRecord but I need an OR option and it seems that the only thing the searchFilter passes is AND. I saw this post "[NetSuite And/Or Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640582/netsuite-and-or-filter)" which gave me the the correct information but I keep getting the following error.

> Title     SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_EXPR_OBJ_TYPE
>   Type    System
>   Details     filters

and I am not sure why, I tried to do a search for the Error title "SSS_INVAILD_SRCH_FILTER_EXPR_OBJ_TYPE" but google did not produce any helpful information.

Here is the Expression Code I am running

```
filterExpr = [
                    ['internalid',null,'is',itemId],
                    'AND',
                    [
                        ['inventorylocation',null,'is',locationId],
                        'OR',
                        ['inventorylocation',null,'is',3]
                    ]

                ];

var results = nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,filterExpr,columns);
```

--- SOLVED ---

Figured it out the issue was with the null I had in the filter it should have been written as such.

```
filterExpr = [
                    ['internalid','is',itemId],
                    'AND',
                    [
                        ['inventorylocation','is',locationId],
                        'OR',
                        ['inventorylocation','is',3]
                    ]

                ];

var results = nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,filterExpr,columns);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Figured it out the issue was with the null I had in the filter it should have been written as such.

    filterExpr = [
                        ['internalid','is',itemId],
                        'AND',
                        [
                            ['inventorylocation','is',locationId],
                            'OR',
                            ['inventorylocation','is',3]
                        ]
    
                    ];
    
    var results = nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,filterExpr,columns);

Comment: Yes, filter expressions don't require a separate parameter for the joins like nlobjSearchFilter does. Instead, to specify a join in the expression, you can do something like `['customer.email', 'is', 'test@test.com']`

Comment: Thank you for the help I do appreciate it.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh Does that dot notation work in SS v1 for custom record types? I'm getting error SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_JOIN - An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid join ID, or is not in proper syntax: my_custom_field_name. My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494717/sss-invalid-srch-filter-join-when-using-filter-expression-on-joined-custom-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter did not need the null option that I was putting in my bad for not fully reviewing the format.

--- SOLVED ---

Figured it out the issue was with the null I had in the filter it should have been written as such.

```
filterExpr = [
    ['internalid', 'is', itemId],
    'AND', [
        ['inventorylocation', 'is', locationId],
        'OR', ['inventorylocation', 'is', 3]
    ]
];

var results = nlapiSearchRecord('item', null, filterExpr, columns);
```