# SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_JOIN when using filter expression on joined custom field

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

SuiteScript v1.

Searching on the item record type.

customrecord_sp_ecom_item_infoseo is a custom record type with a field called custrecord_sp_ecom_item_seo that references an item record. It also has a field called custrecord_sp_ecom_description, which is of type text.

I want to search for the items where the word "frozen" appears in custrecord_sp_ecom_description in the linked customrecord_sp_ecom_item_infoseo record and I want to use filter expressions.

Here's my expression:

```
[
    [
      "customrecord_sp_ecom_item_infoseo.custrecord_sp_ecom_description",
      "contains",
      "frozen"
    ]
]
```

And here's the error I get:

{"error" : {"code" : "SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_JOIN", "message" : "An nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid join ID, or is not in proper syntax: custrecord_sp_ecom_description."}}

If I change the expression to:

```
[
    [
        "isonline",
        "is",
        true
    ]
]
```

then it works fine, albeit with the wrong results. So I know filter expressions can work, there's just something wrong with my expression.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the dot syntax for joins in filter expressions, the prefix of the dot is the ID of the *field* you are joining through, not the ID of the record type you are joining to (as it looks like you have here).

So, if I am searching Invoices, but I want to filter on the Sales Rep from the related Sales Order, it would look something like:

```
[
  [ 'createdfrom.salesrep', 'anyof', salesReps]
]
```

Notice that it's not `salesorder.salesrep`, but rather `createdfrom.salesrep` because the `createdfrom` field is what links the record I am searching (Invoices) to the record I am joining (Sales Order). The same applies when using custom records. Your join will be something like `custrecord_fieldid.custrecord_sp_ecom_description` rather than using the record type.

Comment: Thanks. I actually knew this from my use of nlobjSearchFilter and joins but from the examples I'd found online I'd concluded that I was supposed to use the record type name when joining in filter expressions. Hopefully your answer will now prevent anyone else from repeating my mistake!

Comment: Is it possible to search invoices by Customer in this way? Looks like entity on the Invoices table shows Customer name. But, seems to return a number and not the name.